# How to implement idle time out using java script function in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell how to implement idle timeout using java script function in sencha touch

I have tried in sencha  controller

```
var timeoutTime =60000;
    var timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function() { alert("dd"); }, timeoutTime);
    **$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').bind('mousedown keydown touchstart', function(event) {**
        clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
        timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function() { alert("dd"); }, timeoutTime);
    });
});
```

I am getting error $ in undefined

Comment: Where did you called jquery file?

Comment: @SagarKhatri  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').bind('mousedown keydown touchstart', function(event)  this two lines am getting error

Comment: I am asking for `file`. Where did you added the url for loading `jquery`?

Comment: in sencha touch controller am called the above code

Comment: You should add remote file reference in app.json so that jquery will loaded for execution.

Comment: @SagarKhatri which file i need to add in app.json? jquery libray?